# Task Scheduler fails to start on WIndows 10 (Insider Build 1903 (18362.1)

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, windows-task-scheduler, task-scheduler, windows-insider

I don't often deliberately reboot my PC but it is set to accepting Windows 10 Insider updates (Fast ring) and update overnight. As a result, it's usually up and it was only recently, that I noticed that the Start+typing option was not working. Further investigation showed that every Microsoft App as well as Edge would not accept keyboard input (I tried the inbuilt laptop keyboard, a wired USB keyboard and a Logitech wireless keyboard). Other programs and apps were fine.

Rebooting took forever (I suspected a BCD boot problem, but it eventually started), but didn't fix it.

A web search finally showed that the problem was fixed by using Start+R and running CTFMON, which handles alternative input and the language bar. This fxed the actual issue, but further investigation showed that the reason it wasn't started was that the Task Scheduler hadn't started so the task MsCtfMonitor hadn't run to start CTFMON.

The event log shows several Service Control Manager errors, mostly to do with network service, task scheduler is not mentioned.

Has anyone else identified a possible cause of this?

Obviously, a web search hasn't come up with anything yet and the workaround is simply to start CTFMON and all the non-started automatic services after each boot.

By the way, booting off a DVD into a recovery system boots normally.

Comment: Using beta-test software means that you agree to willingly suffer such problems.

Comment: I'm not complaining, just enquiring if someone else has seen this and identified the cause and a fix. There was a version last year which screwed up booting on some PCs (including mine). The fix was to repair the UEFI boot partition and avoid updating to that specific build, The next one worked fine.

Comment: So you longer experience the behavior?  Sounds like it was a bug that was fixed.

Comment: The complete boot failure some months ago had a fix. The CTFMON failure is presumably still there, but I haven't rebooted for several days.